# How to find middle record in sql server with writing a function new function?

Tags: sql-server

For example there are five  record in a table i want to find third one how you create function for any count of elements

Comment: Which column(s) you want to use for the ordering?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH CTE AS( SELECT RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Column ASC), t.* FROM dbo.Table t )
SELECT * FROM CTE
WHERE RN = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Table) / 2 + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
SELECT TOP 3 * FROM tab EXCEPT SELECT TOP 2 * FROM tab
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option which doesn't generate and extra field is using the **WITH TIES** clause

```
Select Top 1 with ties *
 From  YourTable
 Order By case when row_number() over (Order By SomeValue) = (Select count(*) From YourTable) / 2 + 1 then 1 else 2 end
```